# Angular returning status code 0 instead of 302

Tags: angularjs, https, mixed-content

Angular has its own status code 0 for failed request. I am trying to make API call on keeping my app open for 30-40 minutes.

When i make a call the API request hits the server and it redirects to the login page hosted by other application.When I make any API call I can see in fiddler the response 302 and should be redirected to the login page.

The problem is that the it is being redirected to HTTP and my app is using HTTPS so the angular giving mixed content error in console.

I wrote responseError Interceptor to capture the status code 302 and do some manipulation on the Location header and redirect to transform the URL to HTTPS instead of HTTP. That doesnt seem to work.In resposeError I could only see response code 0 instead of 302.

Is it necessary to send the access-control-origin header with the redirect request from the server?

Could someone please help here or suggest a way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Only status codes beginning with 4 or 5 are errors. Consequently an interceptor for errors will only be called when you get one of those codes or the request fails for other reasons.

You will also never get a 302 in your JavaScript code because the browser will always attempt to follow the redirect.

Your problem is having [mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent) (http and https). CORS has nothing to do with it. Fix your server to send a URL with the correct protocol.